# I have a shapefile containing three types of polylines, how can I color each type with different colors?

Tags: shapefile, arcgis-engine

I have a shapefile containing three types of polylines, how can I color each type with different colors ?

Comment: What software do you prefer to use?

Comment: Shapefiles only store data—but not style.

Comment: Do you also have access to arcmap?

Comment: Mahdi, welcome to our site!  I suspect your question has collected some downvotes and no really specific replies because people may feel that more information is needed within the question itself.  Consider editing it to say a little more about the shapefile (especially how the "types" of polylines are distinguished) and about the context of the application you are creating.

Answer (score 2):

Whichever software you use, you should be able to display the line colours differently based on an attribute of the line itself. e.g. Road = black, river = blue etc.

In Mapinfo this is done using thematic mapping, in Arc you edit the symbology.

Comment: how can I change the line attributes using ARcGISEngine + C#,there is no line attributes in shapefiles, thanks in advance

Comment: In a shapefile, the attributes are stored in the .dbf file.  If there isn't an attribute for the three types of lines you want to color, you can always create a new field and give each record one of three values (1,2,3; red,blue,yellow; high,medium,low; etc), then display the lines differently based on that attribute.